# How do I store a SecureString in the registry?

Tags: .net, windows, registry

I want to store a System.SecureString in the registry. Is that possible? And how would I go about doing it?

Would my program be able to decrypt the string again when running the next time?

Comment: I guess it applies to storing in the registry - [How to save a secureString to a file?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d4557d9b-6e7d-4695-bfd0-a22a08e06160/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do in encrypted form without a helper layer.  It' doesn't natively support any form of serialization and in fact cannot even be inspected in it's native form.  To even get any information out of it you need to go through PInvoke or the `SecureStringToBSTR` API.  Both of which will give you access to the `string` in unencrypted form.

One way I could see this working is

1. Convert the `SecureString` to a `BSTR` via `SecureStringToBSTR`
2. Encrypt the `BSTR`
3. Store the result in the registry

Of course you'd need to use an encryption mechanism which was re-usable between instances of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Storing Private Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722457%28VS.85%29.aspx) article in MSDN.  You'll have to pInvoke the LsaStorePrivateData() call.